# HttpContext.User.Identity.Name está retornando nulo no ASPNET Mvc Core

Tags: c#, mvc, asp-net-core, ioc

Preciso buscar o nome do usuário logado na máquina, na camada de `repositorio/conexão` com banco para poder substituir o `User Id` na minha `connection strings` para realizar a conexão.

Estou usando a injeção de dependência para, injetar o `HttpContext.User.Identity` na minha camada de `repositório/conexão` porém quando tento executá-lo o `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` sempre me retorna um valor nulo.

Meu `Startup.cs` onde regitro as dependências:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddScoped<IUsuario, Usuario>();
        services.AddScoped<Db>((arg) => new Db(arg.GetService<IUsuario>()));
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Minha `IUsuario` classe onde injeto meu `HttpContext`

***Usuario.cs***

```
public class Usuario : IUsuario
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    
    public Usuario(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    
    public string GetUserName()
    {
        return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    }
    
}
```

***IUsuario.cs***

```
public interface IUsuario
{
    string GetUserName();
}
```

Minha classe de conexão onde injeto minha classe `IUsuario` para pegar meu nome

```
public class Db 
{
    private IUsuario _usuario;
    
    public Db(IUsuario usuario)
    {
        _usuario = usuario;
    }
    
    public SqlConnection AbrirConexao()
    {
        var username = _usuario.GetUserName();
        var stringConexao = string.format("Server=xxxx; User Id={0};....", username);
    }
    
}
```

O erro que aparece quando tento rodar a aplicação.

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Fica a dúvida é possível fazer isso, logo quando a pessoa entra no sistema buscar o `"usuario"` e autenticar no banco? Se não for existem alternativas?

*Obs: Minha aplicação roda na intranet.*

Comment: *"usuário logado na máquina, na camada de repositorio/conexão"* não deveria fazer isso, quem tem acesso aos objetos com essa informação, se a session, identity, token, etc, é a primeira camada, deveria lá pegar isso e passar por parâmetro para o repositório

Comment: *"substituir o User Id na minha connection strings para realizar a conexão"* isso deveria ser feito automaticamente usando por exemplo "impersonate", procure sobre isso e vai encontrar alguns exemplo... veja sobre string de conexão e tem como fazer isso com o usuário autenticado: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax

Comment: @RicardoPontual é feito assim porque cada usuário da rede interna tem um cadastro dentro do banco, por causa de permissões e etc... Concordo também que não seria de responsabilidade das camadas mais "baixas" da aplicação, mas como fazer isso então? Criar uma classe na camada de apresentação que retorne a string de conexão já formatada e injetá-la no repositorio?

Comment: @RicardoPontual inclusive dei uma olhada no link que você recomendou, e acho que funcionaria se eu não tivesse uma DLL de acesso ao banco a parte, onde eu tenho que passar a `string` em determinado formato e ela dentro ela formata baseado nos meu parâmetros e me devolve a conexão

Comment: Entendi, de qualquer forma, acho que o caminho que faz mais sentido é o repository receber o user como parâmetro, ou ele começa a ganhar mais responsabilidade que deveria :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual mesmo mudando para a camada de `repositorio` o problema continua o mesmo, o que eu não entendo é que se rodo no modo `debug` pelo `Visual Studio`, o problema não existe, agora se compilo e rodo ele via `dotnet run` ou publico, ele me dá esse erro que não consegue acessar o `IHttpContextAcessor`

Comment: O IHttpContextAcessor é acessível no contexto da Web, ou seja, no ASP.Net, Api, etc, por isso precisa obter a informação e já passar para o componemte de repository, mas é possível registrar o `IHttpContextAccessor` e injetar no repository  como você fez, tem um exemplo, aqui, veja se ajuda: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0